# How to keep logic files separate and use in cs files in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am very new to .net, Is there way to keep logic files are separated and reuse in cs files?

Comment: why you people down voted, when i am getting the answer for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aman Khan, Create new dir App_Code keep your logic file there and use to your project as shown in below image

[image]

and you call define

using System
using CMS

Answer (score 2):

Create a C# Class Library Project and add its reference to your project.

Comment: How i can add refernce?

Comment: @amankhan references->add reference? Google it, please ... Maybe look for something like: `create c# project tutorial`

Comment: Check this here is full example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse the files.Place all the logic files in seperate folders  like App_Code and just copy the code and use it. 
Happy coding :)